# MultipleLinearRegression returns the same value everytime

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, python

I got 1000 answers from developers via Google Forms. Question was about salary, where did they learn programming, and when they understood that there is no need for any physical courses, or instructors. Then I encoded all answers with some numbers, and used Multiple Linear Regression for predicting, for example, if developer learnt programming by himself, how much can he get money ? Now the problem is, my codes every time returns only value between 3.7 - 3.8. What can be problem ? Here are my python codes:

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv("forms.csv")
print(data.columns)

salary = data.salary.values.reshape(-1,1)
source_and_understand = data.iloc[:,[1,2]].values

regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(source_and_understand , salary )

# source: {1:"By myself", 2:"Course", 3:"University", 4:"Other"}
# when did you understand ? : {1:"From beginning", 2:"After 3 months", 3:"After 6 months", 4:"After year", 5:"When I got my first salary", 6:"Other"}

# Here I enter source and understanding period manually to get different salary values 
index = regression.predict(np.array([[3,4]]))
print(index)
rounded_index = int((index))
salary_list = ['< 100$', '< 500 $', '< 1000$', '> 1000$', 'I have no salary']

try:
    print(salary_list [rounded_index])
except IndexError:
    print(f'Other - {rounded_index}')
```
````

Comment: Two reasons: 1) Maybe salary can't be predicted with just this little information. 2) Both response and features seem to be categorical. It seems that you encoded them as numeric, which often does not make sense.

Comment: @MichaelM, first of all thank you for your response, friend. And yes, that moment disturbed me, all data was in string format, and converting them to integer seems not correct. Is it possible to make these operations with string values ?

Comment: For the features, it is easy: check out dummy / one-hot encoding. For the response, it is delicate as classic linear regression requires numeric output. Here, you have two possibilities: The naive one is to encode the response by integers but in the natural order, not just in a random order. A better way (from statistical view) is to use a model technique for categorical outcomes such as multinomial logistic regression. In Sklearn, sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Comment: @MichaelM I didn't know that displaying mean value according to custom inputs can be so difficult :( Thank you again.